# How to programmatically issue a click event on Android

Tags: android, service

#### Quick version:

*How* could I trigger the event related to an screen touch in a given coordinate, regardless of device state?

#### Longer Version: My Problem:

I have users that are unable to touch the device (they lack body movement, due to [cerebral palsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebral_palsy) or [strokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke)). I am then in the process of creating a device that monitorates other types of input (for instance muscle contraction, or even throat humming, among others).

The important part is that I have a circuit that emits a single command.

These commands must then be intercepted by the Android device, and execute its associated command, as if the user was normally operating the device.

**Note the following:** I will not have any Activity running. The purpose of the application is to interface the sensor with the device, and thus, I cannot make use of View elements.

I suppose what I want to perform is to create a `mouse-like` element for Android.

But I have not come with any way to either have an application be executed inside my own (where I would provide an automated moving "target" for the user to issue a command/click) or a way to perform an [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) or [KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).

While my research so far yielded no response, I would like to ask the following: Am I forgetting any part or directive of the system that could allow me to perform my task?

The final outcome, is a Service, this service is merely waiting for a signal, this is captured by a Receiver... this is where I am stuck.

Comment: That is generally not possible, for security reasons. You are welcome to examine the accessibility APIs, but AFAIK they do not support arbitrary touch operations. You are also welcome to create a custom ROM that provides special hooks for your alternative input. You are also welcome to have your "circuit" implement the USB HID mouse protocol, in which case it should work on most Android devices without any special on-device software.

Comment: The only thing I've seen so far that *is* able to inject touches/events is Espresso.

Comment: @Shark [Monkeyrunner](developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) and other tools can inject motions/gestures, however, they are programatically defined or pseudo-randomized for testing purposes. What I need is a way to interface all gestures with a single input....and I need to do this by giving the user an apk/instructions/whatever, and they execute that without my interference

Comment: @Bonatti so basically, we have two JUnit-based solutions that can inject motions/gestures, but still no *real* way of doing that in the real world.
Tough luck...

Comment: @Bonatti, Yes you are quite about right service is the way to do it.
Now you say that you are capturing a signal of data in receiver,
right? and if yes than thats it you just have to do operation you want in that service.
Let me know if I am getting it wrong cause i am confuse about the last line.

Comment: voice recognition is enough;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to input an answer here, to show alternatives for people that might have similar issues.

From the get go, the device is a stand alone object, that issues GET requests to an internal webserver in the Android device (I am using [PAW server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver) as of today, 26/10/15), and I can issue some simple commands.

Likewise, I am planning to to an Activity with a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), and a cursor that keeps on moving, and when the signal is received, it uses the onTouchEvent of the focusable object under it (still studying.)

I do understand the security "flaw" from what I am trying to do, but even a USB HID (Universal Serial Bus - Human Interface Device) wont work on what I am planning so far, due to the needs of the user.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have a very hard time injecting Events from your app into any other app, due to security reasons.

However, you might have better luck in native land, C/C++. So hopefully your sensor-wrapper will end up as a .SO lib which can be included in other projects...

Because what you're trying to do kinda sounds like what Espresso can do (it's a JUnit test suite that *can* inject Motion/Touch/KeyEvents into views)

However, you can compile your own image with some added accessibility apps that might get you there. But your idea is really not going to be applicable to just about any off-the-shelf android device.

Comment: I am not expert but there is an easy way to reflect events in one App from another app, Broadcast Receiver. you can always sendBroadcast() to other applications with intent actions.

Comment: @SulabhDeepPuri While BroadcastReceivers *can* broadcast Intents with payload (e.g. added extras that describe the event or carry additional information/data) it is *nowhere* near injecting touch/motion events; the original app's onClick() / onTouch() methods will never fire. 

The purpose of the question was about how to inject events caught by his disability app into other apps; not about the mechanism which can be used as a transport layer between the two apps. He needs to connect his app's onTouch() with any other app's onTouch(), not edit the original app's code to fetching it from intent

Comment: @SulabhDeepPuri perhaps you should read the question better and try to understand it next time.

Comment: yeah sure, thanks for the feed back though, at least now i know those was not a good approach..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can insert events while testing because Robolectric, espresso and all the others runs simulations. The best way to do the same in a real device would be sandboxing an app inside yours. That way, your app will act as the OS for the others. But that would be costly and the performance would not be good.

Another alternative is doing the same Xposed does. Xposed intercepts system calls to allow modding the OS without flashing anything, so maybe you could use the same hook (or Xposed itself) to add your listening feature. This will require root, but sounds a lot easier than sandboxing every app in the device or building a custom rom.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Android's accessibility features for developers?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

Also keep in mind that you can use Android as a USB host to external devices, such as homemade trackpads, joysticks, etc (with a bit of hacking probably).
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

As for what might be available on the OS already, take a look at the Accessibility menu in the Settings.  Hope this helps!